# Keep boxes well sized and from moving when zooming/resizing html/css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to keep my boxes from moving when zooming in-out/resizing.

Snippet to my code is here: http://www.bootply.com/qngh4aarVh

I want the three boxes called .col-xs-4 not to move when resizing. I want them to be the same width all up as navigation. I will also later want to make it that when the width is below 480, they appear one under each other, under the carousel.

Thank you for any assistance.

Trying to match something similar to this. http://educationwp.thimpress.com/

Comment: did you tried [Bootstrap Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)?

Comment: I am using col-xs-4, that's part of the grids yeah?

Comment: so if you want it to re-size with the page you should set col-md and col-lg, do you could control the size of the boxes in different window sizes.